# Fasten silicone glasses holder to arm of the glasses

Tags: clothing, personal-care, eyeglasses

I’ve bought a second glasses holder in the hope it won’t keep slipping off the arms. This is an ineffective product design. It is really annoying as I am in the middle of renovating a house. Every half hour I find the glasses are dangling by one arm, and I have to reattach the so called holder.

There must some way I can modify these silicone bands so they attach to the arm and resist moving more than they do. The small spring simply slides back.

[image: Glasses arm showing spring that always loosens it’s grip on the silicone band]

Perhaps a dab of silicone? Crimp the spring? I must not look unsightly.

Comment: It's a VERY effective design when used as designed by the designer. There's a twist to the story, however, that is not widely known. Be the first on your block to do it correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed a loop. Two, in fact, on each end of the glasses holder cord.

Bend the elastic loop in half and put one arm of the glasses through both loops of the "8" formed by the bent loop. For stability, put the neck loop end closest to the frame hinge. The second loop nearer the ear hook is a stabilizer to hold the position on the arm you choose.

Like this:
[image: Eyeglass holder attachment technique]

Good viewing!

Comment: Excellent, and so obvious! I'll try this today.

Comment: So far so good, only one separation in several hours.

Comment: Update: no fails today so you have saved me a great deal of irritation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would try some Sugru in black.  Sugru is a silicone clay you can buy at Amazon or at Target, for example.

You could take a small piece of it and use it to secure the loop to the glasses.  Since it’s black in color, it should be undetectable and keep you looking fashionable.

It’s quite durable; I used it to repair a flexible dongle wire and it’s really holding up to heat, pressure, and continuous flexing.

Good luck!

Comment: I will investigate. Thanks for the idea. Have heard of this stuff but never used it.

Comment: @Stefan It's fantastic stuff; but, it's overkill for this job. BEFORE you do get some, be sure to check the expiry date on the bottom of the package. Many forget that it has a Best Before date. After that, it's not usable.

Answer (score 1):

The silicone loop slides from the *wide* part of the arm towards the *narrow* part of the arm. So you can secure the loop to the glasses as mml suggested, using Sugru or silicone or some other substance. Another option is to place a "stopper" just behind the silicone loop, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

The "stopper" could be a small blob of hot glue (my preference), Sugru, silicone, or any other substance that will stick to the arm of the glasses, and also blends in.

Comment: The stopper is already designed into the product. : ) It's the other half of the end of the neck cord.

Comment: @Stan Ahh!  I see your diagram, and I get it. That would still require friction to hold it in place, which in my experience isn't the best solution. But I haven't tried your solution, and it's cool, so I gave it an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer as such - you already have that from Stan - but a suggestion too long to put in a comment.

A couple of years ago I was doing dome home renovation work and knew that my glasses were going to be necessary - but also would be in harm's way all the time.

Coincidentally, at around that time, I had asked my optician about multi-focal contact lenses and they had given me some trials of a SINGLE lens that gave me close-up vision in one eye.

I found this to be an excellent solution. I would just put the lens in when starting the day's work and basically I had perfect eyesight for the entire day, with no glasses. Even better, they were FREE since they were trials.

I appreciate that the profile of my vision problems are not the same as yours, but it may be worth investigating.

Comment: Very interesting and thanks. How quickly did you adjust to close vision in one eye? (If I have understood you correctly.)

Comment: It took about an hour the first time, then a few minutes each time afterwards. You do sometimes find yourself closing the "distance" eye in order to get a better close-up view, but that passes over time. Also, I was never really comfortable driving with the lens in - but apparently most people do get used to it.

Comment: Now, this is a hack!

Comment: @Stan I suppose it is, never really thought about it like that! I'd heard about the concept of multi-focal contacts and decided to see if they would be any good to me. The optician recommended this as the first thing to try because it is much cheaper. It's strange when you've done it a few times because you can see close-up detail and it really doesn't register in your brain that it's only coming from one eye; both images merge seamlessly. My main problem is with using contacts at all - either I can't get it to go in, or I can't get it out later. It's a work in progress!